# I have 10 nested for loops, all iterating 12 time, which is too many iterations (12^10 I believe) for my computer. How can I make it more efficient

Tags: java, performance

So I have this code

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 12; a++){
            for(int b = 1; b <= 12; b++){
                for(int c = 1; c <= 12; c++){
                    for(int d = 1; d <= 12; d++){
                        for(int e = 1; e <=12; e++){
                            for(int f = 1; f <=12; f++){
                                for(int g = 1; g <=12; g++){
                                    for(int h = 1; h <=12; h++){
                                        for(int i = 1; i <=12; i++){
                                            for(int j = 1; j <=12; j++){
                                                //does something...
```

Yes, it is ugly, but I am more focused on efficiency. I am trying to find 10 numbers, which can be numbers 1 through 12 where numbers in places 1-4 add to 20, numbers in places 4-6 add to 20, numbers in places 7-9 add to 20, and numbers in places 9, 10, and 1 add to 20(trying to solve a puzzle I saw by code). No number can be repeated.

Here is a visualization of the puzzle:

```
a b c d 
j     e  //a+b+c+d need to = 20, same with d+e+f, f+g+h+i, and i+j+a, and no number 1-12 can be 
I h g f  //repeated
```

I thought a way to approach it would be by trying all possible combinations with nested until one works, but this was something my computer was not able to do, in a timely fashion that is. I have been struggling with how to speed this up.

I had another way I attempted it although more complex, I think would be faster, but I struggled to get it to work. This was finding all 4 number combinations of numbers 1-12, that add to 20, and the same with all 3 number combinations of numbers 1-12 that add to 20. Then seeing which combinations of those combinations worked. Is this a better approach? If not how can I improve what I have?

Comment: If a,b,c,d don’t add up to 20, then there’s no point in continuing  the `for`  loops for the rest - put an `if` test there, or replace the `for` loop for d and instead calculate d directly.  Ditto for the other conditions.

Comment: When you say _"1 through 12 where numbers in places 1-4 add to 20"_, what do you mean by _"in places 1-4"_.  Are you referring to the first 4 digits?

Comment: Are you sure your puzzle have a solution ? I made a program to look for them but I couldn't find any. I can give you this code as answer if you want it.

Comment: @racraman, this worked! Thanks for the help. I ended up putting lots of points checking conditions in the loops.

Comment: @Cortard, I was able to get some solutions(624 of them). Thanks for the offer. I can send you the code if you are interested.

Comment: @EliasKrasny, happy for you. Yes please